# Symfony2 : Doctrine - Update table structure on two different entity managers

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have two servers A and B and some mapped entity to Server A and another to server B.

When I execute `doctrine:schema:update` all tables are created on the B server. Any idea why this might be happening?

Here my config.yml file

```
# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: A
        connections:
            A:
                driver:       pdo_sqlsrv
                port:         1433
                host:         A
                dbname:       MADB
                user:        
                password:    
                charset:      UTF8
            B:
                driver:   pdo_sqlsrv
                host:     B
                port:     1433
                dbname:   MADB2
                user:    
                password:
                charset:  UTF8

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        default_entity_manager:   B
        entity_managers:
            labete:
                naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
                auto_mapping:    false
                connection:      A
                mappings:
                    HMAdminBundle: ~
                    HMMainBundle: ~
            main:
                naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
                connection:       B
                mappings:
                    HMProfBundle: ~
                    HMMainBundle: ~
                    HMAdminBundle: ~
```

Comment: You're ORMs default entity manager is B - so guess why your schema is updated for B?! So please start reading about how to use more than one entity manager (be careful: this is an advanced topic!).

Answer (score 3):

Your configuration indicates that your default entity manager is B. That's why when you run the doctrine command, tables are generated for B.

When you run doctrine commands, there's usually an entity manager option that you can pass in:

```
doctrine:schema:update --em=A
```

You can see all the options by running:

```
doctrine:schema:update --help
```

Comment: Thanks @asumedic, in fact its more complicated, because I have a ManyToMany relation between a table in B and an other in A, so i think that he cant connect to A cuz when i use --em=B, doctrine want to generate the table from A (only with id) in the B databases :/ any idea ?

Comment: You have manyToMany relationships between entities mapped in multiple entity managers in different databases?

Comment: That sounds like a very bad idea. You should try to keep your mappings within the same entity managers. Otherwise your units of work will be out of sync, creating an utter mess. Use an entity manager per database, but do not cross-map entities between them.